# Rails 5.2, Active Admin add links to index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Using Rails 5.2.3, ActiveAdmin 2.1.0 and aasm 5.0.5 I want to create links for the permitted events for a resource managed by aasm.
I want to show the links for the status change in the index page, it works with this code:

```
  index do
    id_column
    column :status

    actions do |resource|
      item 'pdf', pdf_master_fine_path(resource)

      resource.aasm.events({ permitted: true }, current_user).map(&:name).each do |event|
        item event, polymorphic_path([current_user.role, resource], action: event)
      end
    end
```

In the picture I show the result: the links are created but is printed the entire array.

[image]

How can I solve? I don't want to print the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a naive solution.

```rb
resource.aasm.events({ permitted: true }, current_user).map(&:name).each do |event|
  item event, polymorphic_path([current_user.role, resource], action: event)
end && nil
```